# Disable backspace in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a typing program in which the user types a series of characters, but must do so without any errors. While typing, the user *can* backspace in a word, but the backspace option ends when they press the space bar (moving on to a new word).

Here is my current code:

```
public synchronized void backSpace(){
    if (ttext.length() > 0) {
        ttext = ttext.substring(0, ttext.length() - 1);
    } else {
        typetext.append(" ");
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to *disable the backspace function* so that the user can no longer edit what they have typed.

Comment: swing, webapp, mobile app.. what platform exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) to remove the default backspace action. For example:

```
textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("BACK_SPACE"), "none");
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using Swing you could do this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackspaceCapture extends JDialog {

    public BackspaceCapture() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("A text field");
        textField.getKeymap().addActionForKeyStroke(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, 0), new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    backSpace();
                }
            });

        add(textField);
        pack();
    }

    public void backSpace() {
        System.out.println("Backspace is pressed");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JDialog dialog = new BackspaceCapture();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However since there exists so many way of editing a text field it might be an idea to look at [javax.swing.event.DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to control the text.

Comment: -1, KeyMaps are old functionality and where replaced in JDK1.3 with "Key Bindings". See: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html. For more information on Key Bindings see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html. Also, a DocumentListener would not help since the Document is already updated when the listener fires so the character has already been removed.